# Pandas dataframe: Replace values of columns addressed by index and based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I need to replace values only in certain columns (unnamed, as I have a csv without header) based on some condition.
In particular, I need to replace `""` with `\N`.
For instance, suppose I need to change columns 8 and 9, the following row of the csv:

`964,64448,Alen,,2,1998,A45,,,,(Italy),e02d7543d85d91a772dc9f1cac542751`

Should become:

`964,64448,Alen,,2,1998,A45,\N,\N,,(Italy),e02d7543d85d91a772dc9f1cac542751`

I CANNOT DO THIS WITH `SED`, I must use python

So I am loading the csv:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(filename, quotechar='"', escapechar="\\", dtype=str, header=None)
```

and, suppose `columns` is the list of indices of the columns I must change, I would do the following:

```py
columns = [8, 9]
df.iloc[:, columns] = np.where(
    df.iloc[:, columns] == "", "\\N", df.iloc[:, columns]
)
df.to_csv(...)
```

This approach does not throw any error but simply does not work and changes nothing in the output file. I think because iloc returns a view and not a copy of the df, but not sure.
I have tried with `df.iloc[:, columns].replace("", "\\N", inplace=True)` but the result is the same, probably because the operation must be done on the same `df.iloc[...]` object.

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas is reading your csv as if it has a header but no data. You at the very least need to set `header` to None:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data', header=None, dtype=str)
```

Then you can go about replacing the columns by their index/default name (starts at 0), and writing the output:

```
df[7].fillna('\\N', inplace=True)
df[8].fillna('\\N', inplace=True)

# Get rid of any other 'NaN' as they were read in blank
df.fillna('')

# Write the output, also stripping the header:
df.to_csv('out', header=None)
# Output:
# 0,964,64448,Alen,,2,1998,A45,\N,\N,,(Italy),e02d7543d85d91a772dc9f1cac542751
```

Same concept here, but now doesn't inject NaN into the blank places:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data', header=None, keep_default_na=False)

df[7].replace('', '\\N', inplace=True)
df[8].replace('', '\\N', inplace=True)

df.to_csv('out', header=None)
```

Comment: Neither approach works. The output is:
`25107,1615418,Raideen,\\N,2,1975,R35,\\N,\\N,\\N,(Italy),51c64b1feba6e9593e425fb6e91ee32f` (So the backslash is not escapted)
Also, as far as I know, df[n] filters the nth ROW, not column

Comment: `df[x]` selects a given column / Series within a dataframe. It's working on your example text, and I only have 1 line read in.

I'm not getting `\\N` in my example, weird. Can you show a line of text directly from the csv, not once it's read in via pandas? Not sure if that's part of the issue

Comment: The line I posted originally is from the csv. For me, only the second approach works (meaning it replaces the blanks only in the columns I want it to, and leaves the others blank). But it is still inserting \\N, and if I don't escape the backspace inside the string, it doesn't even run

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) after reading your file:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, quotechar='"', escapechar="\\", dtype=str, header=None)

df = df.fillna({7: r'\N', 8: r'\N'}).fillna('')
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Output:

```
964,64448,Alen,,2,1998,A45,\N,\N,,(Italy),e02d7543d85d91a772dc9f1cac542751
```